# How to select perticular part of image and zoom that part using jquery?

Tags: jquery, image

I have two images layered on each other using z-index. I just want to zoom a particular part of those images but this zoom is such that I will select a area using mouse i.e. clicking on a part of image and dragging mouse and releasing the mouse button and that much part will get zoom.
So please tell me is such thing is possible in jquery?
if yes how could i do that?

Please guide me friends!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin: http://benjaminmock.de/bezoom-jquery-plugin/

It doesn't do exactly what you want - it's designed to allow interactive "magnifying glass" zooming. You might be able to adapt it however; it's not very complicated. Basically, you'd watch the mouse movements, and then apply the length-to-width ratio of your selection rectangle to grab a region of the actual image.

Comment: Not what he wants. He wants to specify an area and zoom to that with the mouse. Hard to find.....

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Iviewer](http://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/jQuery-Plugin-for-Image-Zoom-Rotation-Plugin-iviewer.html) jquery plugin does what you need.

Iviewer is a jQuery UI based jQuery plugin that allows you to zoom in/out, rotate and move images in area by the mouse on your web page.

[DEMO site here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-for-Image-Zoom-Rotation-Plugin-iviewer/test/)